# unhealthy docker container not restarted by docker native health check

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-engine

I have implemented docker native health check by adding HEALTHCHECK command in Docker file as shown below,

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=60s --timeout=15s --retries=3 CMD ["/svc/app/healthcheck/healthCheck.sh"]
```

set the entry point for the container

```
CMD [".././run.sh"]
```

executing the docker run command as shown below,

```
docker run -d  --net=host --pid=host --publish-all=true -p 7000:7000/udp applicationname:temp
```

healthCheck.sh is exiting with 1, when my application is not up and I can see the container status as unhealthy,   but it is not getting restarted.

```
STATUS

Up 45 minutes (unhealthy)
```

Below are the docker and OS details:

```
[root@localhost log]# docker -v
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
```

OS version

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
```

How to restart my container automatically when it becomes unhealthy?

Comment: Your `docker run` command appears to be invalid. The `net` option needs to be `--net` rather than `-net`, and host networking is incompatible with publishing ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker only reports the status of the healthcheck. Acting on the healthcheck result requires an extra layer running on top of docker. Swarm mode provides this functionality and is shipped with the docker engine. To enable:

```
docker swarm init
```

Then instead of managing individual containers with `docker run`, you would declare your target state with `docker service` or `docker stack` commands and swarm mode will manage the containers to achieve the target state.

```
docker service create -d  --net=host applicationname:temp
```

Note that host networking and publishing ports are incompatible (they make no logical sense together), net requires two dashes to be a valid flag, and changing the pid namespace is not supported in swarm mode. Many other features should work similar to `docker run`.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/

Answer (score 4):

There is no auto restart mechanism for unhealth container currently, see [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/22719), but you can make a workaround as mentioned [here](https://github.com/willfarrell/docker-autoheal):

```
docker run -d \
    --name autoheal \
    --restart=always \
    -e AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL=all \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    willfarrell/autoheal
```

It add docker unix domain socket to the monitor container, then it could monitor all unhealthy container and restart it for you if other container is not healthy.